# Why are Cpt. Branson's hands cable-tied in this shot?

Tags: alien-franchise, alien-covenant

[image]

This isn't a head scratching, convoluted plot question. I'm just curious as to why  the charred remains of James Franco (aka Captain Branson) has its hands cable tied together? Is that just a thing they do with burned corpses?

I guess I'm bothered by his death and am looking for some kind of extra conspiracy behind it. Of course the cable tied hands couldn't have had anything to do with it - they were obviously put on *post-mortem*. But still...

Comment: Don't you know *anything* about zombies?

Comment: I would guess it is because they didn't want the arms flopping around off the litter.

Comment: I heard in the uncut version the corpse was also accused of a crime of indecency, under complex space maritime law, and thus placed under arrest.